# How to connect external database at run time in custom module drupal 8

Tags: drupal

I am a drupal8 developer. I want to connect to other external database in module. Likewise in D7 it's something like this:

```
$other_database = array(
      'database' => 'databasename',
      'username' => 'username', // assuming this is necessary
      'password' => 'password', // assuming this is necessary
      'host' => 'localhost', // assumes localhost
      'driver' => 'mysql', // replace with your database driver
  );
  // replace 'YourDatabaseKey' with something that's unique to your module
  Database::addConnectionInfo('YourDatabaseKey', 'default', $other_database);
  db_set_active('YourDatabaseKey');

  // execute queries here

  db_set_active(); // without the paramater means set back to the default for the site
  drupal_set_message(t('The queries have been made.'));
```

I tried this in D8 but it's throwing an error. Can you help me in this regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After connecting to the external DB you should clear your cache pragmatically.
Below is the code snippet:

```
    $database = array(
          'database' => <your_database_name>,
          'username' => <your_username>, 
          'password' => <your_password>, 
          'host' => <host>,
          'driver' => 'mysql',
          'port'    => '3306',
          'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql'
      );
    \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::addConnectionInfo('<your_key>', 'default', $database);
    db_set_active('<your_key>');

    drupal_flush_all_caches();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use db_set_sctive method in drupal 8 like this

`\Drupal::Database->setActiveConnection($key)`